# Atlassian Bamboo installation failing to start

Tags: batch-file, bamboo

I've installed Bamboo on my machine and I'm trying to run it. Every time I call bin\start-bamboo.bat from the command line it fails to start and I can't figure out why. Here's is what I have in my cataline.log:

> 23-May-2017 17:34:41.938 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Valve} Setting property
>   'resolveHosts' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
>   23-May-2017 17:34:41.943 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR
>   based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
>   production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\matth.dnx\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator
>   Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program
>   Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\matth\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin;C:\Users\matth\Downloads\mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.tar\mysql-connector-java-5.1.42;.
>   23-May-2017 17:34:41.989 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8085"] 23-May-2017 17:34:42.003 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read 23-May-2017 17:34:42.005 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization
>   processed in 299 ms 23-May-2017 17:34:42.014 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service Catalina 23-May-2017 17:34:42.014 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 23-May-2017 17:34:53.384 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars
>   At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
>   debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were
>   scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during
>   scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>   23-May-2017 17:34:53.404 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
>   listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
>   appropriate container log file 23-May-2017 17:34:53.585 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom
>   Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using
>   [SHA1PRNG] took [179] milliseconds. 23-May-2017 17:34:53.585 SEVERE
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context []
>   startup failed due to previous errors 23-May-2017 17:34:53.643 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"] 23-May-2017 17:34:53.649 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 11644 ms

And here's what I have in my localhost log:

> 23-May-2017 17:34:53.401 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 23-May-2017
>   17:34:53.402 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error
>   configuring application listener of class
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.setup.BootstrapLoaderListener
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/atlassian/bamboo/setup/BootstrapLoaderListener : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.setup.BootstrapLoaderListener) at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2544)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:858)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4764)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 23-May-2017 17:34:53.403 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error
>   configuring application listener of class
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.ww2.actions.setup.BambooContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/atlassian/bamboo/ww2/actions/setup/BambooContextLoaderListener :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.ww2.actions.setup.BambooContextLoaderListener) at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2544)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:858)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4764)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 23-May-2017 17:34:53.404 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error
>   configuring application listener of class
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.upgrade.UpgradeLauncher
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/atlassian/bamboo/upgrade/UpgradeLauncher : Unsupported major.minor
>   version 52.0 (unable to load class
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.upgrade.UpgradeLauncher) at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2544)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:858)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4764)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 23-May-2017 17:34:53.404 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error
>   configuring application listener of class
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.session.SeraphHttpSessionDestroyedListener
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/atlassian/bamboo/session/SeraphHttpSessionDestroyedListener :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.session.SeraphHttpSessionDestroyedListener) at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2544)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:858)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4764)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 23-May-2017 17:34:53.404 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped
>   installing application listeners due to previous error(s)

If anyone could help that'd be most appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is within the stack trace:

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Check the Java versions - 52.0 is Java 8: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout

Latest versions of Bamboo require JDK 1.8 (Java 8)
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/supported-platforms-289276764.html

But Bamboo is starting with Java 7:

> ...C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin...

So you need to upgrade your current JDK, or install another JDK and point it to that.

Comment: Thanks for the response and you're correct. I figured this out a few days after having posted the question.